# Circuit to switch charge controller inputs +18V non-regulated panel vs 12V regulated panel

Tags: solar-cell, charger

Problem: Multiple input voltages that need to be sorted.

Solution: Switch the current path based on voltage level:

*Path 1* - Battery terminals (panel has been regulated to 12V)

OR

*Path 2* - Rooftop solar input terminals (panel is unregulated and 18V or higher)

**What should go into this unlabeled box in the middle to sort the inputs?**

I hear that a Schmitt trigger may work?

Solution must be able to pass 30A.

[image]

Comment: Impossible to choose unless you have more specs for all loads and conditions (Charge manager?) Do you know how MPPT works?  go read.

Comment: Really what I want is anything lower than 15 volts to go to the "REG" side and to the battery side terminals of the battery.

Answer (score 0):

Your cheapest solution is two power diodes rated for 30A at 85’C not 125’C on a heat sink using Diode - OR logic . With over voltage protection OVP.

Comment: Reached out to a few more sources and it appears that the best way to do this is leveraging a supervisory circuit with set voltage thresholds and mosfets in an H bridge config.  5V from supervisory circuit chip triggers mosfet gate.

Comment: MPT control is the most efficient solution which satisfies all out/in spec needs